# Laravel query many to Many

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need help.I have 2 tables `products` and `categories`:
[image]

[image]

Get request sends category id. My question is: how to build a query using the product model??? (The query looks like this: Output the product where the category id is equal to $ request-> category). Table connections are configured, I only need the query, (I read the documentation, but do not not understand it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($categoryId) {
   $q->where('id', $categoryId);
})->get();
```

Read about [querying relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Of course you need to have configured `Product` model with `categories` relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You've said it's many-to-many relationship, all relations are configured and you want to use `Product` model to build a query. In this case, you should use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
Product::whereHas('categories', function($q) use($request) {
    $q->where('id', $request->category);
}))->get();
```